# How to add counter to top of table instead of bottom

Tags: html, css

I have following , where in i am adding counter to table using css

**HTML**

```css
body {
  counter-reset: Serial;
}

tr td:first-child:before {
  counter-increment: Serial;
  /* Increment the Serial counter */
  content: counter(Serial);
  /* Display the counter */
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover sortable" id="numbers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">number#</th>
      <th scope="col">Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS to Add update the table dynamically

```js
$("#numbers tbody").prepend("<tr><td></td><td>" + number + "</td><td>" + formattedTime + "</td></tr>");
```

which gives me results

[image]

the **FIRST column** is 1,2,3.... i ***want it to be 3,2,1 and so on .....***

Comment: There was no JavaScript in your question, so that tag was misleading. Then, please include HTML along with CSS if you want someone to reproduce your problem and try to solve it. Third, this was literary among first two results of the google search: https://jsfiddle.net/teleject/sZmvV/

Comment: Sorry about that , I have added the details, All I wanted to do is, As I am prepending the other details, i want to add number along with it